# Domains for a Sorcerer with Domain Access

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization

Domain Access from Complete Champion p52 allows a sorcerer to take a cleric domain for the price of forever losing one L1 and one L2 spell known. The sorcerer gets the domain power, but can cast the domain spells (using his sorcerer spell slots) only 1/d.

I was looking at the Time domain and the Charm domain.

Time gives you Improved Initiative for free, and has some nice spells.

Charm gives an untyped bonus of +4 to charisma 1/d, and has situationally useful spells (so the 1/d isn't likely a problem).

What domains offer the greatest utility and/or power? Are there other domains with a better synergy with sorcerer features?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Good domain allows you to cast spells with a +1 caster level. While by itself, the power is hardly impressive, it has excellent synergy with the Aligned Spellcaster ACF (DR357). You sacrifice gaining a familiar to add the [Good] descriptor to all of your spells (in addition to a further CL bonus vs evil aligned/subtype creatures). This means that every spell you cast (maybe not evil spells) gains the +1CL from the Good domain power. There are metamagic feats that can also add the [Good] descriptor to spells, but I find this method to be less effective. For further [Good] descriptor synergy, throw in Spell Focus(Good) (BoED) to gain +2 DC on all spells with the [Good] descriptor. Yes, it's more powerful than Spell Focus(School) and applies to every spell you cast. Maybe a little cheesy, but balance is always a delicate thing in 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately it depends on what else you're doing with your character: pick something that will synergize.  Time and Charm are solid choices, so you're off to a good start.  The turning/rebuking powers are a mixed bag: only useful if you encounter the creatures in question, and if you look at the rules for turning, it's actually not a great way to gather minions (take the Necromancy or Deathbound domain and make Skeletons instead).

Here are some suggestions (from Spell Compendium):

- Celerity: +10 feet movement speed all the time. Spells include Haste, Wind Walk, and Time Stop.
- Domination: Focus(Enchantment) as a bonus feat.
- Dream: Immunity to fear effects.
- Inquisition: +4 on dispel checks.
- Illusion: Illusion spells at +1 caster level.
- Pestilence: Immunity to disease.
- Planning: Extend Spell as a bonus feat.
- Conjuration: Conjuration(summoning) and (calling) at +2 caster levels.

Naturally, you should check with your GM before you use anything from non-core books.

Answer (score 3):

Time and Charm seem good. Celerity gives Blur and Haste one level late, which is not the way these spells should be used (and +10 to land speed is not much after first levels - just get yourself a steed for open places and a fighter for tight places). Deathbound is ok, if you go that way. Destiny is not bad if you care about your friends AND your DM allows to use Delay Death version from Spell compendium instead of that from Races of Destiny (maybe swithcing the order with Bestow Curse or some such). Domination is ok. Dragon Below from Eberron is good mechanically, but might not fit from RP standpoint. Inquisition is good. Luck, Meditation and Planning are not bad, especially if you play them to the top. Portal is not bad in most settings and might be very good if your setting uses a lot of portals. Shadow could be rather versatile; you will probably take the best spells from it anyway, but if for some reason you do not, it is an ok choice. I wonder why no one mentioned Travel - it is really good.

I'd choose from Time and Travel first; Charm, Destiny, Inquisition and Luck second. Maybe Portal. Would depend on starting level, character theme, game, party composition, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A few from the Spell Compendium that haven't been mentioned:

The **Lust** domain would be quite badly broken if it was allowed -- you get to add your class level to your charisma for one round, which would be just ridiculous at high levels, if used with a save or die spell.  (Well, it says cleric level, but I believe there's clarification *somewhere* that this translates to class level.)

The spell list makes it more of the Creepy Stalker domain, though.

**Family** has a handy defensive ability (+4 dodge bonus to everyone within 10 feet, pretty much) and a bunch of spells sorcs wouldn't normally have.  If you wanted to help out the party it would be good.

**Wrath** would be nice for a sorc focusing on melee (maybe a dubious choice, but some people like a challenge), since its ability lets you 1/day sacrifice wisdom for strength.  The spells would be likewise useful for such a build.

It was already mentioned, but I want to stress that **Inquisition** could be really good if you wanted to combat mages -- the +4 to dispel checks is actually pretty powerful for a sorc, who can (and should) always have *dispel magic* or the like handy.  There are some additional spells in the PHB2 and spell compendium that let you make dispel checks, and a relatively cheap item in the Magic Item Compendium that would give you a further bonus.

Lastly, the **Heal** domain could be an interesting choice.

Answer (score -1):

The War domain gives proficiency and weapon focus in your deity's weapon, and I believe the Metal domain does the same for a selected hammer type.  Otherwise the domain ability really depends on the campaign world.  The elemental domains allow you to turn the opposing element's outsiders.  The Death domain could kill a weakened foe without using a spell slot and not giving them a save (pesky Improved Evasion).  Being +1 caster level from the Healing domain never hurts since your caster level is a bonus to the healing spells within, and even if it's "just +1" you would be surprised how effective that is, especially at those critical early levels.  I would highly discourage taking the "Magic" domain, of course as it emulates at a lower level something you should already have a knack for doing.

Comment: Why would a Sorcerer want the War or Metal domains?

Comment: Admittedly it's at its best at early levels for the domain power when your maximum spells are low and you might have to get in there personally.  But the War domain also gives the Power Word spells as an option.  In the Metal domain the support options (if you don't use the spells on yourself) are quite astounding.